# Java short primitive type issue

Tags: java, android, enums, short

I'm building an application which requires connection with server with post method and gets the result. I need to get the particular part of the server response and convert it to different types of primitives (from `String` to `short`, `int`, `byte` etc.)

So basically I need to get a part of the response code and convert it to short, than see if there is an `enum` element with this value.But the problem is that the response returns value `001` and after I convert it to short and pass it to my `getByValue(int)` method in `enum`, it's saying me that there is no element with 001. If i print the `short` value I get `1`.

Here is a sample of code which I'm using :

```
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters));

            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            Log.v("Response ","Status line : "+ response.getStatusLine().toString());
            String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()); //response
            Log.v("Response ","Response : "+ responseBody);

            int objectIdentificator = Integer.parseInt(responseBody.substring(0,32));
            Log.v("Response ","Object Identificator (LONGINT) : "+ responseBody.substring(0,32));
            Log.v("Response ","Object Identificator (LONGINT) : "+ objectIdentificator);

            String type = responseBody.substring(32,35);
            Log.v("Response ","TYPE (UNSIGNED BYTE) : "+ type);
            short pType = Short.parseShort(type); // short 
            Log.v("Response ","TYPE (UNSIGNED BYTE) : "+ pType);

            String operation = responseBody.substring(35,38); //
            short operationType = Short.parseShort(operation);
            Log.v("Response ","OPERATION (UNSIGNED BYTE) : "+ operation);
            Log.v("Response ","OPERATION (UNSIGNED BYTE) : "+ operationType);

            String objectId = responseBody.substring(38, 70);
            Log.v("Response ","UID (CHAR, length 32) : "+ objectId);

            int id = Integer.parseInt(responseBody.substring(70, 102));
            Log.v("Response ","ID (LONGINT) : "+ responseBody.substring(70, 102));
            Log.v("Response ","ID (LONGINT) : "+ id);

            String size = responseBody.substring(102,134);          
            Log.v("Response ","Data Size (LONGINT) : "+ size);

            String hash = responseBody.substring(134,166);
            Log.v("Response ","Data Hash (CHAR, length 32 : "+ hash);

            String  dType = responseBody.substring(166,169);
            Log.v("Response ","Data Type (UNSIGNED BYTE) : "+ dType);
            short dataType = Short.parseShort(dType);
            Log.v("Response ","Data Type (UNSIGNED BYTE) : "+ dataType);

            String data = responseBody.substring(169, responseBody.length());
            Log.v("Response ","Data (CHAR, any length, in BASE64) : "+ data);

            byte[] first = Base64.decode(data);
            String string = new String(first, "UTF-8");

            Log.v("Response ","BASE 64 : "+ string);


            RPCPacket packet = new RPCPacket(   objectIdentificator,
                                                RPCPacketType.getPacketTypeByValue(pType),
                                                RPCOperationType.getByValue(Integer.parseInt(operation)),
                                                objectId,
                                                id,
                                                Integer.parseInt(size),
                                                hash,
                                                RPCPacketDataType.getByValue(dataType),
                                                first
                                                );


            Log.v("PacketType", "RPCPacketType : "+packet.packetTypeToStr(RPCPacketType.getPacketTypeByValue(pType)));
```

And packetTypeToStr code :

```
public String packetTypeToStr(RPCPacketType type){

        String str=null;
        switch(type){
        case ST_OBJECT_TYPE_INFO_START: 
                str = "ST_OBJECT_TYPE_INFO_START"; 
            break;
        case ST_OBJECT_TYPE_INFO_ERROR: 
                str = "ST_OBJECT_TYPE_INFO_ERROR"; 
            break;
        case ST_OBJECT_TYPE_COLLECTION: 
                str = "ST_OBJECT_TYPE_COLLECTION"; 
            break;
        case ST_OBJECT_TYPE_CATEGORY: 
                str = "ST_OBJECT_TYPE_CATEGORY";
            break;
        case ST_OBJECT_TYPE_CARD: 
                str = "ST_OBJECT_TYPE_CARD"; 
            break;
        case ST_OBJECT_TYPE_MESSAGE: 
                str = "ST_OBJECT_TYPE_MESSAGE"; 
            break;
        case ST_OBJECT_TYPE_GENRE: 
                str = "ST_OBJECT_TYPE_GENRE"; 
            break;
        case ST_OBJECT_TYPE_TAG: 
                str = "ST_OBJECT_TYPE_TAG"; 
            break;
        case ST_OBJECT_TYPE_USER: 
                str = "ST_OBJECT_TYPE_USER"; 
            break;
        case ST_OBJECT_TYPE_MEDIA_COLLECTION: 
                str = "ST_OBJECT_TYPE_MEDIA_COLLECTION"; 
            break;
        case ST_OBJECT_TYPE_MEDIA_CATEGORY: 
                str = "ST_OBJECT_TYPE_MEDIA_CATEGORY"; 
            break;
        case ST_OBJECT_TYPE_MEDIA_CARD: 
                str = "ST_OBJECT_TYPE_MEDIA_CARD"; 
            break;
        case ST_OBJECT_TYPE_MEDIA_TAG: 
                str = "ST_OBJECT_TYPE_MEDIA_TAG"; 
            break;
        case ST_OBJECT_TYPE_INFO_END: 
                str = "ST_OBJECT_TYPE_INFO_END"; 
            break;
        case ST_OBJECT_TYPE_CARDSTATS_CATEGORY: 
                str = "ST_OBJECT_TYPE_CARDSTATS_CATEGORY"; 
            break;
        case ST_OBJECT_TYPE_CONTENT: 
                str = "ST_OBJECT_TYPE_CONTENT"; 
            break;
        case ST_OBJECT_TYPE_MEDIA_COLLECTION_BUTTON: 
                str = "ST_OBJECT_TYPE_MEDIA_COLLECTION_BUTTON"; 
            break;
        default: 
                str ="UNKNOWN "+type;
            break;
        }

        return str;
    }
```

And the exception :

```
09-08 09:53:08.744: WARN/System.err(2509): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: no datatype with 001 exists
09-08 09:53:08.754: WARN/System.err(2509):     at com.stampii.stampii.comm.rpc.RPCCommucatorDefines$RPCOperationType.getByValue(RPCCommucatorDefines.java:34)
09-08 09:53:08.754: WARN/System.err(2509):     at com.stampii.stampii.user.UserLogin$2.onClick(UserLogin.java:122)
09-08 09:53:08.754: WARN/System.err(2509):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
09-08 09:53:08.754: WARN/System.err(2509):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8817)
09-08 09:53:08.754: WARN/System.err(2509):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
09-08 09:53:08.754: WARN/System.err(2509):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-08 09:53:08.754: WARN/System.err(2509):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:144)
09-08 09:53:08.754: WARN/System.err(2509):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4937)
09-08 09:53:08.754: WARN/System.err(2509):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-08 09:53:08.754: WARN/System.err(2509):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
09-08 09:53:08.754: WARN/System.err(2509):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
09-08 09:53:08.764: WARN/System.err(2509):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
09-08 09:53:08.764: WARN/System.err(2509):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

RPCOperationType code :

```
public enum RPCOperationType {
        O_CREATE(1),
        O_UPDATE(2),
        O_DELETE(3);

        private int value;
        private intvalue1;
        private RPCOperationType(int i){
            this.value=i;
        }
        public int getNumericType(){
            return value;
        }
        public static RPCOperationType getByValue(int i) {
             for(RPCOperationType dt : RPCOperationType.values()) {
                 if(dt.value1 == i) {
                     return dt;
                 }
             }
             throw new IllegalArgumentException("no datatype with " + i + " exists");
         }

    }
```

So any suggestions how can I solve this issue without changing the id's in enum?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You've shown us nothing about the enum - such as how you find the enum value based on the ID. It seems to me that that's the important bit...

Comment: Are you saying the `IllegalArgumentException` is thrown?  Is it thrown with the message "no datatype with 001 exists"?  That doesn't quite make sense, as ints don't print that way.  Can you tell us exactly what you see?

Comment: how are you passing pType to getByValue?

Comment: qustion updated with more information

Comment: If you parse the string, obviously 00 will be removed since they do not change the value at all. You need to keep it as a String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception is not thrown by the code you showed us. The stack trace says where the exception occurs:

```
at com.stampii.stampii.comm.rpc.RPCCommucatorDefines$RPCOperationType.getByValue(RPCCommucatorDefines.java:34)
```

It's thus the call to `RPCOperationType.getByValue()` in `RPCCommucatorDefines.java`, at line 34 that throws this exception. You're certainly passing it a String, and not an int, BTW, because there is no way for a short variable to be printed as `001` as it's done in the error message of the exception.

The two first lines of a stack traces are the most important one. The first one telle you what's wrong, and the second line tells you where the exception is thrown.

Comment: The exception is thrown in getByValue method exactly the same as the one shown in the question.

Comment: No. as I said, read the stack trace, and show us the code of the RPCOperationType.getByValue method, which is at line 34 of RPCCommucatorDefines.java. It's impossible for this code to be the same as the one you showed us.

Comment: I saw that in getByValue I take String type,not int..so I edit it as string and now the error says "no datatype with 1 exists".

Comment: It would help if you showed us the real code of the enum, and the code which calls it. The code you showed us doesn't compile. And in your loop, you campare i to value1, whereas this value is never initialized by the constructor. compare it to value.

Comment: As I said: remove the field value1 from the enum, and compare i to value instead of value1 in the loop. Your code still doesn't compile as is thouh: you have a line "private intvalue1;" instead of "private int value1;"

Answer (score 0):

If you need to pad a number with zeros, you'll have to **use [Formatter](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html)**.